# Abstract DI Container Scopes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm in the process of refactoring one of my open source projects, branch [here](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/tree/MoveToStructureMap).

The basic idea of the refactor is to allow for classes and all of its children in the graph to be scoped. I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://andersmalmgren.com/2015/06/23/abstract-di-container-scopes/).

The container is abstracted into an interface:

```
public interface IScopedContext : IDisposable
{

}



public interface IScopedContext<out TEntryPoint> : IScopedContext where TEntryPoint : class
{
    TEntryPoint EntryPoint { get; }
}
```

StructureMap implementation:

```
internal sealed class StructureMapScopedContext<TEntryPoint> : IScopedContext<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    private readonly IContainer nested;

    public StructureMapScopedContext(IContainer container)
    {
        nested = container.GetNestedContainer();
        nested.Configure(config => config.For<IScopedContext>().Use(this));
        EntryPoint = nested.GetInstance<TEntryPoint>();
    }

    public TEntryPoint EntryPoint { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        nested.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Basically after refactoring you can do:

```
public class Host
{
    private readonly IScopedContext<MyWorker> myWorkerContext;

    public Host(IScopedContext<MyWorker> myWorkerContext)
    {
        myWorkerContext = myWorkerContext;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        using(myWorkerContext)
        {
            myWorkerContext.EntryPoint.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it a solid design? Any pitfalls?